# Sources for retracting an incorrect statement

Tags: sources-mekorot, talmud-gemara, tanach, mussar-ethics, mishna

Is it brought down anywhere, something to the effect that if one realizes he was incorrect in a matter (can be a Torah-related matter, or a secular matter), he must retract his statement?

Preferably, I am looking for a source in *Tanach*, *Mishna*, or *Gemara*.

Comment: http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0223.htm#7

Comment: @DoubleAA Thank you, but I'm looking specifically for a source about retraction.

Comment: If you realize there is no soure, will you retract this question?

Comment: @YeZ There would be no source telling me I have to :)

Answer (score 4):

The fifth chapter of *Avos* says one hallmark of a *chacham*, wise person, is that *mode al haemes*, he acknowledges the truth. *Rashi* says this refers to someone who has erred and acknowledges a correction.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. [The Life Work of Shimon haAmsoni. Aggada Insight by Rabbi Yitzchak Blau](http://blog.webyeshiva.org/the-life-work-of-shimon-haamsoni-aggada-insight-by-rabbi-yitzchak-blau/)

Cited in Talmud Bavli no less than four times, this braissa  first appears in Pesachim (22b)See the Art Scroll page 22b3 notes 27 - 30

> Shimon HaAmsuni- some say Nechemia HaAmsuni- was doresh all the ‘esem’
>   (the appearances of the word ‘es’) in the Torah. Upon reaching ‘Es
>   Hashem Elokecha tirah,’ he was poresh (he divorced himself from his
>   work). His disciples inquired: ‘Rebbe- what will be with all the esem
>   that you have been doresh?’ To which he replied: ‘Just as I have
>   received reward for my drisha, so too will I be compensated for my
>   prisha.’ Until R’ Akiva came and was doresh that ‘Es Hashem Elokecha
>   tirah’ is coming to include [the fear of] talmidei chachamim.

Some of the meforshim that I have seen explain that it was the retraction that allowed Rabbi Akiva to conclude that this es referred to Talmidei Chachomim. That a true talmid chacham would act in this way.